# Bootstrap Navbar how to get it so it can slide horizontally across the top from offscreen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, mobile, navbar

OK, here we go. I have a website texasranchesandlandcompany.com that mimics desktop icons as a navbar. which works fine on the desktop, but when the screen goes to mobile sizes I need to be able to slide those desktop looking icons across the screen horizontally. Without the rest of the website moving with it.

I am not the best coder obviously but this problem has been the bane of my existence for the last 48 hours now.

im not to sure why the snippet looks so ugly, but as you can see im new to coding and I cannot for the life of me get the icons to slide horizontally from offscreen

```css
.fullnavbox {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900);
 [am-LatoSans] {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
[am-TopLogo] {
  max-height: 119px;
  max-width: 210px;
  margin: 12px 11px;
}
[am-CallNow] {
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
/*
  Relevant styles below
*/

.topper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.expbar h2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#9f9f9f, #535353 3%, #1f1f1f 17%, #212121 49%, #191919 89%, #000000 100%);
  border-top: 1px inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar .nav {
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.icons {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar .nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.navbar .nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /*text-shadow: 0px -1px black, 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);*/
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.nav>li>a:hover {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: rgba(10, 91, 196, 0.45);
  border: 2px solid rgba(10, 91, 196, 0.45);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li.active {
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
.nav>li>a>img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:active {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.navfoot {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- NAVBAR -->

<div class="container-fluid fullnavbox">
  <!-- Topper w/ logo -->
  <!-- <div class="row hidden-xs topper">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
      <a href="home.html"><img am-TopLogo alt="SECUREVIEW"  src="pics/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
      <div class="americap">
      <h3>A Wholly owned Subsidiary of the <a href="http://www.theamericapgroup.com">Americap Group</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0 text-right ">
      <p am-CallNow>214-425-9327 CALL NOW<br>For Available Properties</p>
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center expbar">
      <h2>EXPERIENCE ,  not just selling, but in Developement &amp;  Restoration</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Topper -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> -->
        <ul id="navbox" class="nav navbar-nav js-nav-add-active-class">
          <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Our Offices<br>For 24 years<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/daloffice.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">Our Prime Properties<br>Are The Best<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/hcroad.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="388acre.html">388 Acre<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/reserve.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="senior.html">Senior<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/palma.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="countryclub.html">Country Club<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/plant.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="countrydev.html">Country<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/county.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="countryacre.html">Country Acrerage<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/LasHa.jpg"></a>
          </li>
          <!-- <li><a href="countryacre.html">Ranch<br>Developement<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/icon.jpg"></a></li> -->

          <!-- <li><a href="lakestown.html">Lakeside Townhouses</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><a href="ranchdev.html">Ranch Developement</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><a href="about.html">About<br>Us<img class="img-responsive" src="pics/reserve/1.jpg"></a></li> -->
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact<br>Us<img class="img-responsive icons" src="pics/icons/quill.jpg"></a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row navfoot">
      <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-xs">
        <a href="home.html">
          <img src="pics/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="americap">
          <h3>A Wholly owned Subsidiary of the <a href="http://www.theamericapgroup.com">Americap Group</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally, on mobile, you would list nav items vertically down the page, not horizontally.  This is the way I would do it.  I am not sure what you mean by get the icons to slide horizontally from off screen, please describe the exact requirements you have.  Regardless, it would be better to do it vertically from a usability point of view.

Comment: Believe me I wish I could but sadly thats not what needs to be done. by slide from offscreen I mean the horizontal single hieght navbar must stay, however it should bi in a scrollbox except with the actual scrollbox slider hidden, so you can swipe left to right to view the other navbar items. I am sorry if I dont make much sense what im trying to do I have not seen before so explaining it is hard.

Comment: The `@import` CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except `@charset` rules.

Comment: You could take a look at the Bootstrap carousel.  The functionality you are describing is similar. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/